# Which are the user and password for the Postgres database inside the thingsboard/tb-cassandra Docker container?

Tags: postgresql, docker, passwords, thingsboard

The Docker image for Thingsboard with Cassandra (thingsboard/tb-cassandra) also has a Postgres database to store metadata among other things.

I need to connect to this Postgres database from outside the container with a monitoring and administration tool.
For that, I need the user and password that were provided for the database when the image was created, and I couldn't find this information in the Thingsboard documentation.
I don't want to change the credentials because that might cause problems with the other components of the Docker container.

Does anybody know this user/password combination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [thingsboard compose file](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/blob/master/docker/docker-compose.postgres.yml):

```
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: thingsboard
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
```

And according to [Postgress](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres):

> `POSTGRES_USER`
>
> This optional environment variable is used in conjunction with POSTGRES_PASSWORD to set a user and its password. This variable will create the specified user with superuser power and a database with the same name. If it is not specified, then the default user of `postgres` will be used.

So user/password should be `postres/postgres`.